# cv2 motion capture, .avi files are stretched - Python

Tags: python, opencv, video, avi

So Im trying to make my webcam capture motion, and I how to register motion is going fine but with all these nested while loops my save files are dragged to 30 min long and not 10 sec like intended. I can't figure out what Im doing wrong.

What I mean by dragged out is that I record for 10 sec, but when I go into my files to review the footage it's 30 mins of just some frames.

The idea is to make it register motion and then record for 10 seconds and save the recording as a .avi file.

```
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import time


vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

ret, cur_frame = vid_capture.read()
prev_frame = cur_frame

capture_duration = 10
motion = False

while True:    
    frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(cv2.cvtColor(cur_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), cv2.cvtColor(prev_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

    if frame_diff.max() > 150:
        motion = True

    if motion:
        start_time = time.time()
        name = str(datetime.now().date()) + "_" + str(datetime.now().time().hour) + "-" + str(datetime.now().time().minute) + "-" + str(datetime.now().time().second) + ".avi"
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(name, fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
        ret, cur_frame = vid_capture.read()

        while time.time() - start_time < capture_duration:
            if ret:
                out.write(cur_frame)
                cv2.imshow('Input', cur_frame)

            else:
                break
        
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    motion = False

    prev_frame = cur_frame.copy()
    ret, cur_frame = vid_capture.read()

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
    
vid_capture.release()
```

Comment: your code may run very fast and it may create ie. 100 frames every second. But `20.0` in `VideoWriter` doesn't write it in  video with speed 20 FPS but it only inform players that they have to display 20 frames per second. But if you create 100 frames per second so finally it wll need  5 seconds instead of 1 second to display it (100frames/20FPS = 5seconds). You have to slow down your code to create new frame every `50ms` - `(1000ms/20FPS)` - you could try `waitKey(50)`. OR you should use bigger value in `VideoWriter`

Comment: @furas This def helped with the stretched files, thank you, but now the problem is that I only see the frame that actually captures the motion, and not what I want to capture after the fact.

Comment: if you want display frame then you should use `waitKey()` after `imshow` because `waitkey` updated window to display new image. And if you don't want to display then don't use `imshow` - you don't need it to write file.

Comment: you run inner `while` which all time write the same frame - you would have to use ` ret, cur_frame = vid_capture.read()` inside this `while`

Comment: shorter `name = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.avi")`

Comment: @furas Now everything works as I intended, Thank you!

Comment: I see one possible problem `cv2.waitKey` not work when window is close - because systems sends keys/mouse events to active window, and when window is close then `cv2` may not get keys/mouse events.

Comment: shorter `motion = (frame_diff.max() > 150)` without `if` and it doesn't need to set `motion = False` in two places. You could do it even without variable `motion` - directly `if frame_diff.max() > 150:`

Comment: honestly, this code could be restructured entirely. I'll offer an answer later today. -- three separate places where a frame is read... not necessary and will add confusion. also all the error checks on VideoCapture are missing. nobody would want to replicate that code three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code may run very fast and it may create ie. 100 frames every second.

But `20.0` in `VideoWriter` doesn't write it video with speed 20 frames per second but it only inform players that they have to display 20 frames per second. But if you create 100 frames per second so finally it wll need 5 seconds instead of 1 second to display it (`100frames/20FPS = 5seconds`).

You have to slow down to create new frame every `50ms` - (`1000ms/20FPS`) - you can try `waitKey(50)`.

**EDIT:**

Because code may need some time to create frame so it may need little smaller dealy in `waitKey` - i.e. `48` - or you may try to measure time inside loop and use

```
waitKey( 50 - (loop_end-loop_start) )
```

---

You run inner `while`-loop which all time write the same frame - you should  use `ret, cur_frame = vid_capture.read()` inside this `while`-loop

---

Shorter:

```
name = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.avi")
```

```
motion = (frame_diff.max() > 150)
```

---

I see one possible problem: `cv2.waitKey` not work when window is closed - because system sends keys/mouse events only to active window, and when window is closed then `cv2` may not get keys/mouse events.

---

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import cv2

vid_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

ret, cur_frame = vid_capture.read()
prev_frame = cur_frame

capture_duration = 10

while True:    
    frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(cv2.cvtColor(cur_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), cv2.cvtColor(prev_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

    motion = (frame_diff.max() > 150) 

    if motion:
        name = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.avi")
        print(name)
        
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(name, fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_time <= capture_duration:
            ret, cur_frame = vid_capture.read()
            if ret:
                out.write(cur_frame)
                cv2.imshow(name, cur_frame)
                if cv2.waitKey(50) == 27:
                    break
            else:
                break
        
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    prev_frame = cur_frame.copy()
    ret, cur_frame = vid_capture.read()

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
    
vid_capture.release()
```